# Div no embebe css

Tags: html, css, div

Ando teniendo un problema con este código. Seguro que es algo muy simple que estoy salteando, pero ya busque bastante y no logro encontrar la respuesta. Div2 y section no están respetando los parámetros que les otorgo, yo creo que la raíz del problema pueda ser de superposición. Actualizado-

css y html

```css
body {
background-color: lightgray;
}
.banner {
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
font-family: monospace;
width: 700px;
height: 120px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.banner img {
width: 700px;
height: 100px;
}
.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
font-family: Arial;   
}
.navbar a {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 16px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
background-color: black;
width: 350px;
height: auto;
color: #fff;
float: left;
}
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: #fff;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
.navbar .icon {
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.navbar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
.navbar a.icon {
float: right;
display: block;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
.navbar.responsive a.icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
.navbar.responsive a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}  
section {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: red;
}
.div2 {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
padding: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hello, world!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uno.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">Publicidad<br><img src="img/banner.jpg"></div>
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home">Inicio</a>
<a href="#news">Noticias</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Iniciar sesión
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<form method="post" action="/login.phtml">
<input type="hidden" id="templateLoginDest" name="destination" value="%2F">
<table style="width: 350px;" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" width="100px"><b>Usuario:</b></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" name="username" id="templateLoginPopupUsername" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>Contraseña:</b></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="password" name="password" size="30"><br><a href="/account/passwordreset.phtml" style="font-size: 8pt;">Recordar contraseña</a><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Entrar!"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div> 
</div>
<script>function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
</script>
<div><section>a</section></div>
<div class="div2">b</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aclara tu problema específico o añade detalles adicionales para destacar con exactitud lo que necesitas.  Por la forma en que está escrito, es difícil determinar exactamente lo que quieres preguntar. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta.

Comment: Hola Matías, para poder ayudarte sé un poco más específico en tu pregunta. Qué div no está aplicando la hoja de estilo?

Comment: Hola, disculpen mi falta de precisión. Lo que sucede es después del script. Cuando dentro de archivo css llamo a section o .div2 ninguna de estas dos dan respuesta, excepto las de mostrarse de forma natural. O sea sin respetar los parámetros que quiero. Los fonts no responden y las img tampoco, creo que debe ser algún problema con float, como si se estuvieran chocando, con 'navbar'. Ahora reviso la página de 'Cómo preguntar' Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes porque te falta cerrar con corchete `}` uno de los `@media`, y por la forma en la que trabajan los archivos CSS en cascada, después de ese error el resto de sentencias no tienen efecto.

Aquí puedes encontrar más información sobre el estilo de cascada [Cascada y herencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascada_y_herencia)

Además, los dos `@media` que tienes, son iguales `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`, con lo cuál te recomiendo que los unas en uno sólo.

```css
body {
background-color: lightgray;
}
.banner {
background-color: black;
color: #fff;
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
text-align: center;
font-family: monospace;
width: 700px;
height: 120px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.banner img {
width: 700px;
height: 100px;
}
.navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
font-family: Arial;   
}
.navbar a {
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 16px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
}
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
background-color: black;
width: 350px;
height: auto;
color: #fff;
float: left;
}
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: #fff;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
.navbar .icon {
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.navbar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
.navbar a.icon {
float: right;
display: block;
}
.navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
.navbar.responsive a.icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
}
.navbar.responsive a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}  
section {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: red;
}
.div2 {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
padding: 50px;
border: 1px solid red;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Hello, world!</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/uno.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner">Publicidad<br><img src="img/banner.jpg"></div>
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home">Inicio</a>
<a href="#news">Noticias</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Iniciar sesión
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<form method="post" action="/login.phtml">
<input type="hidden" id="templateLoginDest" name="destination" value="%2F">
<table style="width: 350px;" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top" width="100px"><b>Usuario:</b></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="text" name="username" id="templateLoginPopupUsername" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>Contraseña:</b></td>
<td valign="top"><input type="password" name="password" size="30"><br><a href="/account/passwordreset.phtml" style="font-size: 8pt;">Recordar contraseña</a><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Entrar!"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div> 
</div>
<script>function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "navbar") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "navbar";
    }
}
</script>
<div><section>a</section></div>
<div class="div2">b</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias, no lo había notado!